# Why can I pass a float to the constructor of Double?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

In the following code, I construct some `Double` variables from `double`, `float`, and `String`. However, according to the documentation, `Double` only has constructors that accept `double` and `String` - not `float`. So how does this code compile?

```
Double d1 = new Double(2.5);
Double d2 = new Double(2.5f); //Why can I pass a float here?
Double d3 = new Double("2.5");
```

Comment: What do you mean double to a float? Where is that code? Here you're only making doubles

Comment: you can see i'm parsing a float value to Double constructor in  Double d2=new Double(2.5f); line

Comment: And *why* are you using `new Double`? You should almost never use `new` with wrapper classes.

Comment: My comment was referring to " i tried passing a double value to float,but it didn't work"... That code isn't here

Comment: FWIW, `Double.parseDouble` should be used on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of casting, Widening Casting (Implicit) and Narrowing Casting (Explicit done)

Widening --> converting lower range to bigger

Narrowing --> converting bigger range to lower (which causes data loss)

so float can be type casted into Double, find picturization view [image]

Comment: The terminology is "widening conversion" (can be implicit) vs. "narrowing conversion" (must have an explicit cast).  The issue is that a narrowing conversion can result in "information loss" - the smaller number has less precision.

Comment: Note that some widening conversions (such as, in the worst case, converting `long` to `float`) can result in a loss of information too. They're just allowed implicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Because a `float` can generally be converted to a `double` without losing precision, the `float` can be automatically *widened* to a `double`. See [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) for information about which types Java will automatically widen.

An exception is noted in the linked document regarding `float`/`double` conversion:

> A widening primitive conversion from `float` to `double` that is not
>   [`strictfp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) may lose information about the overall magnitude of the
>   converted value.

Comment: what is the meaning of losing precision

Comment: @ThilanRavindu You need to read through a tutorial on how floating-point numbers work.

Comment: @ThilanRavindu losing precision means losing a part of the actual value. Like, `(int)2.5f` here you'll lose 0.5